# select 5 records from db to sql variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sql script which will pull records from a table, I would like for it to read 5 records from the table where the Id=4 then store the Id's to use later in the script

```
DECLARE @ITEM1 INT
DECLARE @ITEM2 INT
DECLARE @ITEM3 INT
DECLARE @ITEM4 INT
DECLARE @ITEM5 INT

SET @ITEM1 = (SELECT Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4)
SET @ITEM2 = (SELECT Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4)
SET @ITEM3 = (SELECT Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4)
SET @ITEM4 = (SELECT Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4)
SET @ITEM5 = (SELECT Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4)
```

Im not sure the best way to read the Id values pulled into my 5 variables

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use table variable (or temporary table)

```
declare @Temp_Items (ID int primary key, Num int identity(1, 1))

insert into @Temp_Items
select top 5 ID from dbo.PageElement where TypeId = 4
```

So you will have 5 rows which are numerated by `Num`. BTW, usually it's better to add `order by` to the query.

Now you can fetch `@Item<N>` like `select ID from @Temp_Items where Num = N`.

Comment: As indicated, a table variable seems like the correct approach.  The following link provides an overview: http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx

Comment: @RomanPekar What syntax to I use to access the first, or second, Id in the table?  Meaning the Id retrieved from the select

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Top 5 from dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4
```

This is easiest way

```
Select Top 5 Id from dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4


SET @ITEM1 = (SELECT Top 1 Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4)
SET @ITEM2 = (SELECT Top 1 Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4 and id not in( SELECT Top 1 Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4))
SET @ITEM3 = (SELECT Top 1 Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4 and id not in( SELECT Top 2 Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4))
SET @ITEM4 = (SELECT Top 1 Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4 and id not in( SELECT Top 3 Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4))
SET @ITEM5 = (SELECT Top 1 Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4 and id not in( SELECT Top 4 Id FROM dbo.PageElement WHERE TypeId = 4))
```

Comment: How can I modify the statement to read the Ids into my @ITEM variables?

Comment: notice that I have declared 5 variables at the beginning of the script, after the select statement, I would like ITEM1 to contain the id of the first record found, ITEM2 to contain the id of the second record found, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT TOP 5`

```
SELECT TOP 5 Id FROM dbo.PageElement
WHERE TypeId = 4
ORDER BY NEWID() -- Optional if you want them randomised
```